# Expectation of multiplication of dependent variables

Tags: expectation

Let $N(t)$ have Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda t $ (meaning, expected value of $\lambda$ events per hour. What is the expectation of:

$N(6) \cdot N(10)$? (The expected value of the number of events in 6 hours multiplied by the number of events in 10 hours)

What I've tried is:

$E(N(6) \cdot N(10))=E(N(6)\cdot (N(6)+N(7,10)))=E(N(6)^2 + N(7,10)))=E(N(6)^2)+E(N(6)E(N(7,10)))=E(N(6)^2)+6\lambda \cdot 3\lambda$

But I got stuck calculating $E(N(6)^2)$

Comment: What is $N(7,10)$ in this connection?

Comment: @StefanHansen The number of events between time 7 to time 10, forgot to mention that. I'll accept your answer when it lets me, thanks.

Comment: The expected number from time $6$ to time $10$ is $4\lambda$.

Comment: Every N(7,10) should read N(6,10), in particular E(N(7,10)) should read E(N(6,10))=4λ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
{\rm E}[N(6)^2]=\mathrm{Var}(N(6))+{\rm E}[N(6)]^2
$$